# Pegar variavel parametro função JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, react

Como eu faço para pegar um parâmetro de uma função e usar para pegar uma variável?
Por exemplo, nesse código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'joao',
    age: 18
  }
  set = (s, v) => {
    this.setState({s: v})
  }
  get = (s) => {
    return this.state.s;
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.set('name', 'maria')}>Mudar Nome</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.set('age', 20)}>Mudar Idade</button>
        {this.get('name')}
        {this.get('age')}
      </div>
    );
    };
}
```

Eu queria passar no get('name') e na função get fazer algo como:
return this.state.name;
Mas não retorna isso, parece que ele usa só o s

Como fazer isso? Qual nome disso?
(esse código eu fiz só para exemplo mesmo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você mudar o seu método `set` para

```
set = (s, v) => {
    this.setState({
        [s]: v
    })
}
```

(note os `[]` envolvendo a chave `s`) você deve atingir o seu objetivo. Isso chama-se [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Exatamente isso o que eu precisava, mas isso só funcionou no set, no get deu problema de:
./src/pages/home/index.js
  Line 19:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  17 |   }
  18 |   get = (s) => {
> 19 |     return this.state.[s];
     |                       ^
  20 |   }
  21 |   // template
  22 |   render() {

Comment: Como você escreveu o get?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/oqerulexol.js

Answer (score 0):

Nesse seu caso dá pra fazer assim:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "João",
      age: 18
    };
  }

  handleName = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.dataset.name
    });
  };

  handleAge = e => {
    this.setState({
      age: e.target.dataset.age
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleName} data-name="Marcelo">
          Mudar Nome
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleAge} data-age="22">
          Mudar Idade
        </button>
        {this.state.name}
        {this.state.age}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Atualizei o código.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta diego, te dei um +
Mas esse código foi só para exemplificar mesmo, a questão é como passar por parametro um S, e nesse S transformar na variavel que eu preciso, sem precisar fazer desse jeito ou ter que fazer algo como:
  get = (s) => {
    if(s == 'name')
    return this.state.name;
    else if(s == 'age')
    return this.state.age;
  }